# how can i create automatic file backup to save to cloud storage?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-storage, cloud, backup

I have 4 workstations (windows) that I need to backup and save to gloud storage, I would like it to be automatically. it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine to set up, on each workstation a planned task that performs a [gcloud rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) regularly in dedicated folder on Google Cloud Storage (and that get the correct folder from the local workstation)

Comment: Thanks for the help Guillaume.
  I've been researching about rsync, but I have some doubts about how to use rsync on windows, should it be used with any app or can it be configured by the windows taskbar? and also on how to have a method to ensure that the backup was actually made without errors.

Comment: rsync is simply a tool that sync the local directory with the remote directory. No more. It's not a backup tool for windows, no error checks, no scheduling, no auto-detection on file change. Run rsync to send the changed/new file to the cloud on a scheduled done by task scheduler on windows. If you fear to erase valid file on GCS with corrupted new file (with rsync), you can activate the versioning on GCS (and set a lifecycle to purge the old versions)